# Paypal language selection method

Tags: paypal, localization

Does anyone knows where to find documentation about the exact method that Paypal uses to choose the language that is shown to the buyer when using a credit card on Express Checkout?

In that Paypal login screen Paypal lets you change yout country and sometimes you got weird results on language selection (For example, using Express Checkout API parameters you enter on  Paypal in Spanish, then change to Morocco, browser is in French, and you get final language in Spanish, ¿?.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it uses lc.

You can get more detailed description about methods here:

https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables

Under *HTML Variables for Displaying PayPal Checkout Pages*

Comment: Thanks. But when you are on Paypal login Page (by credit card for example..) you can change country, and then is when Paypal makes as assumption about the language that you want the page to be translated to. That's the point where I want to find some information about what variables are taken into account.